# ¿En c++ es posible hacer una lista/vector etc de matrices con diferentes dimensiones?

Tags: c++, array, lista, matrices, vectores

Hola quisiera saber si existe un metodo o algo en la STL para guardar matrices de diferente dimension por ejemplo:

```
m1 = {{0,1}
      {2,1}};
m2 = {{0,1,4},
      {5,4,0},
      {6,7,5}}; 
lista = {m1, m2};
```

Comment: Coloca un `std::array` adentro de otro.

Comment: me podrías explicar mejor :)?

Comment: Para `m1` dale el tipo de `std::array<std::array<int, 2>>`. Recuerda incluir `<array>`